# How to achieve Typescript type safety with a middleware system based on the context of the middleware

Tags: typescript

I am trying to create an extensible middleware system, that saves and runs middlewares depending on the context they are linked to. This works, but I have not been able to achieve type safety. For some reason, you are able to use middlewares on a context that is not specified in their interface generic, making them crash at runtime if the middleware were to use a property or method not implemented on the passed context.

I have created a very simple demo implementation of this system on the Typescript playground, the link is [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-T2oNyxQii8UcwqOnkABT0LDowgo9pMkKm+Wb+X0mDqHqSFKpZ0HV1QQpFvDFHk2A-+RVNmdeVoWyzNUSzlqWgznVaSy4HWGogoAhHuXjEKBMZnNh-BR6Jx9cV9CuGVBWvUA3fdXlAHArzvC1HyJH8IIPJY40cEdEg-HMkR-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-uhrBYFgYcwgEQgUuUdAyYWIKGdCwD1JR+AnAoaRbMEYRyExlLQHQUAAANTIay3TToRHREVg4FkwAByThkGqc3Gmlvn3Ns+Q1ZseB+m4UIRG109riWUAAHUBFBgHqdnA2wD2LB+heo4iBwUDcVAq8sFQD2YUyHqMQoeTCeJ3gufJgXZ0IAVvN8pnAtZmuOZJsmecb6tm+nYWO7FtP47hzgCl4fQnBBwgKHkdkjdNPK2GjwCAegPY6gJm6Yd4WH5H6ABRZgQsndnXrrhDefyibpoH5SAFZ5W6woDvgI6Tv3w-kBPs+3JnVQA1VmoBbJP3FmAY+VRp6cCoMQI+VsKpVWAVidgntvYWx4D5bAeBLZvwBIBYQMDT6uTYJSS+nMb79ySIQaUL8kT7UOsdfo9hiFlFISFIBIDLpgLAMgm2aCAZe0AlguwThcDICAA).

Any help with type safety on a system like this is appreciated, I am not sure what's wrong since in my eyes, a superclass should not be assignable to a subclass with extra members.

Comment: I have been able to get the result I want by manually expanding the Middleware interface into the `{ run(ctx: CTX): void }` type. Not ideal but it works for now I guess. This being a valid solution makes me believe it is a compiler bug.

If anyone has any more elegant solutions to something like this please let me know!